# How to use data in the event logs of a smart contract

Tags: solidity, ethers.js

How do you use data in the event logs of a smart contract with Solidity?

For example, I would like to get values like 'src', 'guy', 'wad' from an Approval event in the link below:

https://etherscan.io/address/0x6b175474e89094c44da98b954eedeac495271d0f#events

I'm trying to use ethers.js, but having trouble understanding how to initialize the necessary components (contract, abi, provider, etc.).